# Google Maps API - Get accurate coordinates with business/building name.

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am developing a website in ASP.NET in which I need accurate coordinates of properties and populate their markers on Google Maps. I read the Google Maps API documentation and it doesn't accept business names or house numbers. So if I add 5 properties on Moseley Road with postal code WR2 6NJ, they all receive the same coordinates at the beginning of the road, where as they're all separate properties with separate coordinates, for example: Arthur Amos Associates Ltd, Moseley Farms etc.

How can I increase the accuracy so each address gets it's own coordinates? I tried the ROOFTOP and street_address parameters but they didn't help. Do I need to get Google Maps API for Work to get this level of accuracy?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try geocoding API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: Thank for your comment and I apologise for replying this late. I thought I'll receive email notifications so didn't know there's a comment. Geocoding API works the same way: 

address — The street address that you want to geocode, in the format used by the national postal service of the country concerned. Additional address elements such as business names and unit, suite or floor numbers should be avoided. Please refer to the FAQ for additional guidance.